# Select from a table without column name

Tags: sql, excel, vba

On VBA, I want to make an SQL query to extract data from a CSV file, but the structure of the file is as below:

```
Header 1                        
Header 2                    
field 1 field 2 field 3 field 4 field 5

xxx  xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx

xxx  xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx

xxx  xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx
```

The first 2 lines do not contain important information, so I have to skip the first 2 rows before beginning the query. I tried "SkipRows=2" when opening the SQL connection but it didn't work.

I have already a working query:

```
SELECT [Header 1],count(*) FROM [fileName.csv] where [F29]= 'Rejected' 
GROUP BY [Header 1]
```

This query works fine, but when I try to retrieve data from columns without labels it's not working

Comment: SQL query to extract data from a file... is not quite clear. What file format is it? Does it really need to be SQL? I can't think of any database having 2 headers before the actual fields...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your problem. Writing about, what kind of file it is? Where are you writing the code? What kind of output is required ?

Comment: it's a CSV file. The first 2 lines do not contain important information, therefore I want to skip them and begin the SQL query from the 2nd row. 
I have already a working query (SELECT [Header 1],count(*) FROM [fileName.csv] where [F29]= 'Rejected' GROUP BY [Header 1]
).
this query works fine (I added SkipRows=2 at the opening of the connection), but when i try to retrieve data from columns without labels it's not working.

Comment: is it tab delimited or comma delimited file? I'd prefer following solutions: 1) import everything, and then select needed fields and filter column names, that acceptable for constant structure files 2) delete garbage rows in file, and then import it

Comment: Not the best approach: Open File, Insert Row on Row 1, Add Headers, Save and Close, Do Query.

Comment: I assume *" retrieve data from columns without labels it's not working."* means that after skipping the first two rows that you have no headers left (despite the fact that your first sample clearly shows `field 1   field 2   field 3...`). In your connection I believe you can set the HDR attribute as NO and it will automatically name the columns as F1 to Fn. You can then do `SELECT F1, COUNT(*) FROM ...`

Comment: Besides my answer below it might be a better way to use [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-transform-in-excel-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de)